# Mongoose - How to enable strictQuery for a schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want the query to follow strict mode because if I search for a user and pass in accidentally something not defined in schema i do not want the query to return all documents.

I tried:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },  
}, {strict: true, strictQuery: true});
```

it doesnt work. I also tried:

```
mongoose.set('strictQuery',true);
```

also doesnt work. WHat am I doing wrong?

Comment: When strictQuery is true it removes fields from the query that are not in the schema.  Try setting it to false instead.

Comment: i tried both, but still nothing is happening. If i pass in a field that is not defined in the schema, all users are returned when i search for a user